# "un des meilleurs" or "l'un des meilleurs"?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, articles

> This is one of the best movies this year.

Should this be translated as

"C'est **un** des meilleurs films cette année."

or

"C'est **l'un** des meilleurs films cette année"?

I've seen versions with "un" and "l'un" and I don't understand what the difference is.

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant difference. The variant with *l'un* might be considered slightly more formal, but not that much and not by everyone.

I would have added *de* before *cette année*.

> C'est l'un des meilleurs films de cette année.

or better:

> C'est l'un des meilleurs films de l'année.

Comment: *de l'année*: only if you are talking about the actual year, I would say. *de cette année* can refer to another year you just talked about. Like in English I suppose (*of the year* refers to the actual year, *of this year* can refer to another year if you mentioned it before).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps The question states "this year" which is always the ongoing year in English. Otherwise, "that year" would have been used. PS: Beware about the false friend "actual" which doesn't mean "*actuel*" but "*véritable*".

Comment: A theory of mine: "L'un" contains L apostrophe because we refer to the movie we are talking about specifically like in a movie review, but without L apostrophe we could be talking about all the movies of the year where we are pointing one movie among the list.

Comment: Couldn't adding apostrophe l (for le) reinforces that the movie is one of the best? When I read both sentences I feel with apostrophe l it stresses that it is one of the best. What about that ?